# Continue Does Not Work in Python with datetime

Tags: python, datetime, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to write a program to print all Tuesdays between two given dates and exclude labor day and thanksgiving breaks. However, when I use continue to jump it breaks the loop.

```
import datetime

def getDates():
     StartDate = datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1)
     EndDate = datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 31)
     LaborDay = datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 7)
     Thanksgiving_Start = datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 23)
     Thanksgiving_End = datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 28)
     CurrentDate = StartDate
     days = int((EndDate - StartDate).days)
     print(StartDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
     for NextDate in range(days):
          NextDate = CurrentDate + datetime.timedelta(days=7)
          if NextDate == LaborDay:
               continue
          if Thanksgiving_Start <= NextDate <= Thanksgiving_End:
               continue
          if NextDate > EndDate:
               break
          print(NextDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
          CurrentDate = NextDate

 getDates()
```

Comment: Have you tried printing before continuing or breaking? Just to make certain that you are breaking the loop on a continue and not on the break statement?

Comment: Maybe your if statement is the source - try this: `Thanksgiving_Start <=NextDate and NextDate<= Thanksgiving_End`. You must hold boolean at both sides of `and`

Comment: @Yossi Levi: No, tailed comparisons do work. You can use `0 < x < 10` in Python, no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use  print() you can see that continue is working as espected.

```
def getDates():
     StartDate = datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1)
     EndDate = datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 31)
     LaborDay = datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 7)
     Thanksgiving_Start = datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 23)
     Thanksgiving_End = datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 28)
     CurrentDate = StartDate
     days = int((EndDate - StartDate).days)
     print(StartDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
     for NextDate in range(days):
          NextDate = CurrentDate + datetime.timedelta(days=7)
          if NextDate == LaborDay:
              #labor day is in day 7 from septemeber, this day is not multiple of seven
              #starting from StartDate, so it is impossible that is going to evaluate
              # to true
              print("Continue is working first statement")
              continue
          if Thanksgiving_Start <= NextDate <= Thanksgiving_End:
              print("Continue is working second statment")
              continue
          if NextDate > EndDate:
               break
          print(NextDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
          CurrentDate = NextDate
         

getDates()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that once you encounter the second case, you do not set `CurrentDate`.

In fact, you are mixing two different ways to change `NextDate`. It is set by the loop over the range, but then it immediately gets set to a value related to `CurrentDate`. Pick one and stick with it; otherwise you're bound to run into confusion.

For example, here you could just change your `for` look into a `while True` loop (or better: `while NextData <= EndDate`) ; increment `NextDate` by 7 days; and remove `CurrentDate` from the entire program.

That should make it easier to reason about.